# WebView fails to parse SVG since Chrome 72

Tags: android, google-chrome, svg, android-webview

I'm using a WebView to display an SVG image in my Android app. It worked without any issues up to Chrome 71, but since the update to Chrome 72 I'm getting a parser error:

```
error on line 21 at column 19: AttValue: ' expected
```

Line 21 is this one, and column 19 is the `#`:

```
<g clip-path="url(#clip1)">
```

If I skip over that line, I get the same error on the next line, complaining about the `#efefef`:

```
<g fill-opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" fill="#efefef">
```

It appears like the `#` is causing some issues with Chrome 72. How can I fix that?

---

It seems to be a bug in Chrome. Might be somewhat related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54453987/559745).

I'm loading the SVG with `webview.loadData(svg, "image/svg+xml", "utf-8")`, and if I encode the `#` with `%23` it's working. But why would I have to encode the data by myself?

Comment: I think something seriously broke in Chrome 72, webviews do not expand height any more either.

Comment: May be same as this - https://blog.branch.io/ios-11-safari-view-controller-cookie-passthrough-and-the-future-of-mobile-web/. I'm getting an error similar in percentages of Mobile Safari 12.0 - `28%`, Mobile Safari 11.0 - `18%` and Chrome Mobile 72.0.3626 - `13%` out of 400 events in a single day.

Comment: @RobertLongson as stated in the question, with `webview.loadData()`, loading the plain svg code.

Comment: Chrome fixed their buggy URL parser.

Comment: Apparently `loadData()` uses the `data` scheme internally (in contrary to `loadDataWithBaseURL()`), but still it doesn't make much sense that I suddenly have to encode the data myself.